# GHC-version for Plutus

Tags: plutus, haskell, ghci

This is a short question and probably easy to answer.

Where in the Plutus GitHub repository can I check which GHC-version is needed to compile Plutus ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is provided by haskell.nix. See: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/184f27c67dc696f4dfd558e0ccdfef0f054b519b/nix/pkgs/haskell/materialized-linux/default.nix#L224

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Plutus provides its own patched version of GHC (8.10.4.20210212) through Nix.

Comment: But where can I see this ? Which file in the repository ?